# AAPT error in Android studio while building the project

Tags: android, gradle

I have been getting this error while building my android project. I was not getting this error before but recently I updated my gradle version for supporting instant apps. 
I'm wondering if thats what causing the issue.

> Execution failed for task ':vuclip:processProdAutoFeatureResources'.
>   AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Edit : The code is compiling fine but while building the apk using the command `./gradlew clean build`, the build is failing with the above exception.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
compileSdkVersion buildVersion.targetSdk

defaultConfig {
    baseFeature true
    minSdkVersion buildVersion.minSdk
    targetSdkVersion buildVersion.targetSdk
    multiDexEnabled = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {

    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        versionNameSuffix "-debug"
    }

    e2e {
        initWith debug
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        versionNameSuffix "-e2e"
    }
    auto {
        initWith release
        debuggable true
        versionNameSuffix "-auto"
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
application project(':viuapp')
feature project(':discover')
api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$versions.supportLibrary"
api "com.android.support:design:$versions.supportLibrary"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
api project(':boot')
api project(':utilities')
api project(':analytics')
api project(':viu-logger')
api project(':fonts')
api project(':viu-constants')
api project(':app_context')
api project(':storage')
api project(':datamodels')
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle file?

Comment: Done. This is the build.gradle of my base feature. I guess this is what you want.

Comment: What's the previous gradle version you were working with and what is the one you upgraded to?

Comment: Previously it was 2.3.3 and now it is 3.2.1

Comment: Have you gone over [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues)? Don't know the intricacies of your project.

Comment: yes. It does not contain anything related to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fix it. The issue was I have made one module as library and not added it in my base module. All your feature modules **MUST** be added as a dependency in your play module.

Answer (score -1):

Try:
 File -> Invalidate caches/Restart and Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Please read the question properly. I am getting this error while building my code via build command.